Haskell 3-Way Merge Sort Stack Overflow Exception
I am new to Haskell and functional programming. I am trying to write the 3-way merge sort algorithm in Haskell. Problem is, when I run the code in GHCi it just returns *** Exception: stack overflow. I have been trying to understand the problem, but I got no solution. If anyone can help, I would appreciate it. The code and the output is below.
-- three_way.hs

-- Merge function to merge three sorted lists
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] [] [] = []
merge left [] [] = left
merge [] left [] = left
merge [] [] right = right
merge left middle [] = merge left middle []
merge left [] right = merge left [] right
merge (l:ls) (m:ms) (r:rs)
  | l <= m && l <= r = l : merge ls (m:ms) (r:rs)
  | m <= l && m <= r = m : merge (l:ls) ms (r:rs)
  | otherwise = r : merge (l:ls) (m:ms) rs

-- 3-way Merge Sort function
threeWayMergeSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
threeWayMergeSort [] = []
threeWayMergeSort [x] = [x]
threeWayMergeSort xs = merge (threeWayMergeSort left) (threeWayMergeSort middle) (threeWayMergeSort right)
  where
    n = length xs
    left = take (n `div` 3) xs
    middle = take (n `div` 3) (drop (n `div` 3) xs)
    right = drop (2 * (n `div` 3)) xs

$ ghci three_way.hs
GHCi, version 9.4.8: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( three_way.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
ghci> threeWayMergeSort [2,1]
*** Exception: stack overflow


merge left middle [] = merge lft middle [] doesn't alter the input and just calls itself endlessly same goes for merge left [] right = merge left [] right.

Even once you get it working, it would probably be worth testing if this is significantly, if at all, faster than merge3 x y z = merge x (merge y z).

(Asymptotically, merge doesn't require that you divide a list evenly, only that each half has O(n) length. The 1/3-2/3 split for the second merge would only slow you down by a constant factor.)

(And a 3-way merge sort can only be a constant-factor faster than 2-way merge sort in the first place, so it's not clear the overhead of dealing with 3-way comparisons is worth it.)

You make recursive calls without "progress", like:
merge left middle [] = merge left middle []
merge left [] right = merge left [] right

this thus means that if you call merge [1] [2] [], it just keeps calling merge [1] [2] [].
You thus should in that case perform a 2-way merge.

I added a mergeTwo function as you said and changed the n div 3 to (n+1) div 3. It works now, I guess.
